# Extremely slow ping WIFI on RPI 3 B+, one direction only

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, raspbian-buster

I know that there are lot of WIFI related topics on forum, but I didnt find any similar to mine.

I have barely new RPI3B+, I have installed new Raspbian 4.19.97-v7+.
I have bought Netis wf2123 USB WIFI which uses RTL8192eu module, for installation I used following guide:

http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/faq_detail/id/23.html

but with difference that I have used newest driver working with 4.19 kernel from official realtek github:

https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

After installation WIFI dongle is correctly found by linux. I could connect to my internal network. Internet is working fine with decent DL/UP rates [testspeed run from RPI]:
[image]

Problem is that connecting to RaspberryPi through ssh is almost impossible, when I try ping RPI from my PC (same network) I find connection very unstable:

[image]

Corresponding tcpdump on RPI site looks like:

[image]

In tcpdump above you can see that RPI replies with ICMP reply very fast < 1ms..

However pinging in opposite site (from RPI to PC) looks to work fine (at least much better):

[image]

More info about configuration:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know where could I dig/debug to check where the bottleneck could be, could it be USB bus? Or USB WIFI internal issue?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text - post text

Comment: You show us `iwconfig wlan0` but usually that interface name is used for the built-in WiFi device and additional USB/WiFi dongle are seen with interface name `wlan1`. Do you have `wlan1`? And to confirm @ Milliways: please don't post pictures of text.